# How to iterate on search results from MySQL by PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

When I use

```
 function __construct()
    {
      // open db
      $this->db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
      if (!$this->db)
        die(mysql_error());

      $this->db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
    }


$result=$this->db->query("SELECT OrgNo, CompanyName FROM ematch WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%$word%';");
           $num=$result->num_rows;
          print $num; 
           $i=0;
            while ($i < $num) 
            {
                 $OrgNo=mysql_result($result,$i,"OrgNo");
                 $CompanyName=mysql_result($result,$i,"CompanyName");
                 $i++;
                 print $OrgNo.' '.$CompanyName.'<br>';
            }
```

I get this error:
Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
and nothing comes out.

Comment: This can't be answered, because you seem to be using a custom DB wrapper. We do not know what `->query()` returns

Comment: @Pekka: I think you might be wrong. If $this->db is the mysqli connection, then $this->db->query is the regular query method of the mysqli OO interface.

Comment: @tharkun the mysqli part was edited in later. It makes sense now

Comment: Where does `$word` come from? If it's user input, and not sanitized, your script is open to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). Use prepared queries, turning the pattern for `LIKE` into a parameter. Also, if your host supports PDO (as any host worth its static IP should), use it instead of mysqli. One advantage to PDO is that iterating over results can be done with a `foreach` loop: `<ul><?php foreach ($result as $row): ?><li><?php echo $row['OrgNo'], ' ', $row['CompanyName']; ?></li><?php endforeach; ?></ul>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change your code to this:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT OrgNo, CompanyName FROM ematch WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%$word%';");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  print $row['OrgNo'] .'<br />';
  print $row['CompanyName'] .'<br />';
}
```

Where it is assumed that `$result` returned form your `query` method is a result resource.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to show us the DB wrapper/class you are using but I'd like to have a guess at a way forward:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT OrgNo, CompanyName FROM ematch WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%$word%';");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    print $row['OrgNo']." ".$row['CompanyName']."<br>";
}
```

As you are using a custom DB wrapper youd be better use its way of fetching rows one by one rather than using mysqli_fetch_array();

Comment: It shows a warning for  all mysql function. do I have to add reference or include something?

Comment: @Ahmad Farid - show us or tell us what DB wrapper/class you are using and we can write the code for that wrapper/class and help further

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the semi-colon from your SQL statement.

```
"SELECT OrgNo, CompanyName FROM ematch WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%$word%';"
```

should probably be

```
"SELECT OrgNo, CompanyName FROM ematch WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%$word%'"
```

Comment: Semicolons are SQL terminators, though they're not usually required when accessing MySQL programmatically. They won't cause problems on their own.